# Why doesn't <None Update="" /> work to change copy properties for all files in an SDK style csproj file?

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj

I have an SDK style csproj file with three items that I need copied into the output. I modified the .csproj file as follows

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Impls\SilSidePane\whitepixel.bmp" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <None Update="Impls\SilSidePane\DefaultIcon.ico" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <None Update="Controls\XMLViews\Resources\TextCacheModel_LanguageExplorer.xml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The first two files were copied, but the third wasn't with no information in the logs as to why.

If I instead do the following then the file is copied.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Controls\XMLViews\Resources\TextCacheModel_LanguageExplorer.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Controls\XMLViews\Resources\TextCacheModel_LanguageExplorer.xml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Can someone explain this different behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Depeding on which SDK you're using, `None` may not be the default item that the xml file is added as.

For example, if `TextCacheModel_LanguageExplorer.xml` is an `EmbeddedResource`, then you need to use `<EmbeddedResource Update="..." .../>` instead.

Same goes for `Content` items (e.g. top-level json files in ASP.NET Core applications)

Comment: That makes sense. However, the only page I found describing what goes into which Item is for core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview
@martin-ullrich Do you know of any documentation of what types of files end up in which items by default?

Comment: No, I look at the source code - e.g. the [base .NET SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/d21bc2b61b56208079ca6f8f0b82e14402e25b96/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.props#L32-L40), [ASP.NET Core SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/WebSdk/Worker/Targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker.props#L22-L39) or [WPF SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/master/packaging/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop.props#L2-L34)

Comment: Your answer was useful and I appreciate your effort. The project I'm working on is a Framework project. I looked through the source starting from your links and even searched the dotnet github repo. Still haven't found the root answer. Your explanation is a very sound theory and gave me a good deal more insight into the build. Thank you.